# selenium находит не тот элемент

Tags: python, selenium

я парсю сайт 2gis для удобства  взял ссылку на одну карточку хочу собрать номер телефона но как бы
не пытался постоянно выводит другую ссылку объекта выше.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import time 

def sobiraem_nomer_telefona(driver):
    a = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_t0tx82"]').find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_172gbf8"]')
    return a[2].find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_b0ke8"]').find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@class="_2lcm958"]').get_attribute("href")

driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get(https://2gis.kz/almaty/firm/9429940000800292)

print(sobiraem_nomer_telefona(driver))

time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: А, что вы ждете `time.sleep(5)` в конце вашего скрипта?

Comment: ЭТО ПРОСТО ЧТОБЫ УВИДЕТЬ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ .

Answer (score 0):

Подождать надо, но "до", а не "после":

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located



with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:

    driver.get("https://2gis.kz/almaty/firm/9429940000800292")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    element = wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_b0ke8"]/a[@class="_2lcm958"]'))).get_attribute('href')
    print(element)

------------------------

tel:+77013729028
```

Comment: Тоесть изо того что элемент не успел прогрузится ,selenium находит другой?.